# Webistes listing email address lists for spammers

Tags: email, spam

Which websites would you usually check if you suspect that your company's address book has been leaked and is being used by spammers?

I have identified https://pwnedlist.com/ for this purpose but was wondering if there are another alternative(s).

Comment: While this is the sort of thing that you could ask over on [chat] it doesn't make a good question here.